# How to display image and/or video with intent.ACTION_VIEW

Tags: android, android-intent

In my app i have a marker that displays an image taken by camera intent or  a video. Now the problem I am facing is that when the user tap on the marker and selects " display full image/video"  it should display either the image file associated with the marker or the video file associated with the marker.

I have tried this, but no luck:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri imgUri = Uri.parse("file://" + filep);
intent.setDataAndType(imgUri, "image/* video/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

I then tried below code but when selecting the image (for example) it displays the images but when selecting a marker with a video associated to it; it doesn't play video:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    if (someType == IMAGE) {
    Uri imgUri = Uri.parse("file://" + filep);
    intent.setDataAndType(imgUri, "image/*");
    }
    else 
       if (someType == VIDEO) {
           Uri imgUri = Uri.parse("file://" + filep);
           intent.setDataAndType(imgUri, "video/*");
       }
    startActivity(intent);

    }
```

Is there a way to determine the file associated with the marker and then display the file correctly?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

here is my full code for the intent to display the image/video:

```
.setNeutralButton("Display Full Image/Video",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
     String filep = mMarkerImages.get(marker);
      if (filep != null) {

          Intent intent = new Intent();
          intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
          Uri imgUri = Uri.parse("file://" + filep);
          intent.setDataAndType(imgUri, "image/* video/*");
          startActivity(intent);

            }
    }
})
```

Comment: what is 'someType' ?? what value do you get if `someType ` is NOT IMAGE

Comment: I used `protected static final Object IMAGE = null;`  `protected static final Object VIDEO = null;`  and `protected Object someType;`

Comment: and how you set the value of `someType `

Comment: Am not sure what you mean?

Comment: How you set the value for `someType `.. you are using this variable to determine media type(image/video)

Comment: Could you give an example?  Am struggling to understand

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following ,

```
   public void openFile(String filePath) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + filePath), Utilities.getInstance().getMimeType(filePath));
        if (i.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(i);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "No application found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Here is the method to calculate the Mime type of the file.

```
 public String getMimeType(String filePath) {
        String extension = getFileExtension(filePath);
        String mimetype = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
        return mimetype == null ? "" : mimetype;
    }
```

Comment: I have tried to use your code but with no luck.  I have edited my question with the full code for the intent,  could you possibly assist in showing me what to do?

Comment: @Allrounder Updated my answer, Now its working fine have a look

Comment: Could you possible show me how to implement that in my edited code?  I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Just copy the above two methods into your class, and call the openFile(filePath) method where you want open the file.